# HTTPServletRequest getParameterMap() vs getParameterNames

Tags: servlets, http-request-parameters

`HTTPServletRequest` req, has a method `getParameterMap()` but, the values return a `String[]` instead of `String`, for post data as

> name=Marry&lastName=John&Age=20.

I see in the post data it's not an array, but `getParameterMap()` returns array for every key(name or lastName or Age). Any pointers on understanding this in a better way?

The code is available in Approach 2. Approach 1 works completely fine.

**Approach 1:**

```java
Enumeration<String> parameterNames = req.getParameterNames();

while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String) parameterNames.nextElement();
    String val = req.getParameter(key);
    System.out.println("A= <" + key + "> Value<" + val + ">");
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```java
Map<String, Object> allMap = req.getParameterMap();

for (String key : allMap.keySet()) {
    String[] strArr = (String[]) allMap.get(key);
    for (String val : strArr) {
        System.out.println("Str Array= " + val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are expecting pre determined parameters then you can use `getParameter(java.lang.String name)` method.

Otherwise, approaches given above can be used, but with some differences, in HTTP-request someone can send one or more parameters with the **same** name.

For example:

```
name=John, name=Joe, name=Mia
```

Approach 1 can be used only if you expect client sends only one parameter value for a name, rest of them will be ignored. In this example you can only read "John"

Approach 2 can be used if you expect more than one values with same name. Values will be populated as an array as you showed in the code. Hence you will be able to read all values, i.e "John","Joe","Mia" in this example

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thanks, could you please explain with some post data example, suitable for approach 1 and 2?

Comment: When I try the following url, I get 1 map member (key: r), and its an array with two elements [123123,98734].  https://localhost/app/faces/main.xhtml?r=123123&r=98734

Comment: Often "lost"..is yes, you can (just fine) have ?myQueryStringNameOne=aaa&myQueryStringNameOne=bbb&myQueryStringNameOne=ccc